# How to make an inner DIV move with an outer DIV's scroll position not using fixed width

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll

I have a series of DIV elements that makeup a chart.  The main focus is everything contained within "rightPanel" in the code below.

topPanel has an absolute position and its top value (top: 0px) needs to change when scrolling the rightPanel DIV.  It seems as though my jQuery is correct but it's not firing on the rightPanel scroll event.  See the code below:

HTML

```
Main
  <div class="mainContent">
    <div class="leftPanel"> Left Panel
    </div>
    <div class="rightPanel">Right Panel
      <div class="dataPanel">Data Panel
        <div class="topPanel">Top
        </div>
        <div class="bottomPanel">
            &nbsp;
            <p>Data Data Data Data Data</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.mainContent
{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 3px blue;
}
.leftPanel
{
    width: 225px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: solid 3px pink;
    float: left;
}
.rightPanel
{
    overflow: hidden;
    border: solid 3px orange;
}
.dataPanel
{
    width:21355px;
    height: 3253px;
    border: solid 3px yellow;
}
.topPanel
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 21355px;
    border: solid 4px purple;

}
.bottomPanel
{
    clear:both;
    border: solid red 3px;
}
```

jQuery

```
var sOffset = $(".topPanel").offset().top;
var shareheight = $(".topPanel").height() + 43;
$(".rightPanel").scroll(function() {
    alert('in the function');
    var scrollYpos = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scrollYpos > sOffset - shareheight) {
        alert('inside');
        $(".topPanel").css({
            'top': '61px',

        });
    } else {
        alert('else');
        $(".topPanel").css({
        'top': 'auto',

        });
    }
});
```

And here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LH7g7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the mainContent has the overflow (scroller) not the rightPanel.

You need to hide the main contents overflow, and make the rightPanels overflow display. You will need to set the height for the rightPanel too to make the overflow appear.

Change this in the css:

```
.mainContent
{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 3px blue;
}

.rightPanel
{
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: solid 3px orange;
}
```

then set the rightPanel's height in javascript:

```
 $(".rightPanel").height($(".mainContent").height())
 $(".rightPanel").scroll(function() {'Code here'});
```

Comment: yeah total goof on my part with that...haha.  I need to reword my question, I was trying to set the topPanel DIVs top value to the visible top of the mainContent DIVs scroll value.

But you answered my question so I'll just post that in a new question unless you have a solution ;)

Comment: Trying to understand your question. Do you basically want the top panel to be floating at the top of the rightPanel no matter how far down it has scrolled, so it stays in view?

Comment: Yes.  And unfortunately I can't use "position:fixed" because there is content in the topPanel DIV that leaks out horizontally. 

The only solution I've found is to set the topPanel DIV to position:absolute and manipulate its CSS top value as the mainContent DIV is scrolled.  Just need to get the correct value to move as it's scrolled.

Comment: Its a bit hardcoded, but if you replace the 'top':auto with 'top':($(".rightPanel").offset().top - 31) + "px" on the scroll it will always place it at the top. The offset might help you develop a better answer for yourself, i'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks that cracked it for me!  Big help!